# CRM 2013 WebResource IFrame

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, xrm

I have an HTML web resource in an opportunity that produces a css tab control containing all children opportunity to the current record.

I do this through Ajax and javascript and everything works fine, a new tab is made for each child and it shows an opportunity record inside; the only issue is that it will only show the current record inside of this tab - effectively creating an endless loop.

If I paste the URL from the IFrame into the browser it shows the proper record using the right form that I specify(one that doesn't contain another web resource).

Does anyone know why it wouldn't show the same form as it navigates to? If I try google.com it works, just not for this URL:

```
http://server/CRM/main.aspx?etn=opportunity&pagetype=entityrecord&navbar=off&id=%7B"+val.OpportunityId+"%7D&extraqs=formid%3DC1EC704C-D29B-4786-806F-195D0A80CF07%0D%0A#255409204
```

Comment: Did you try without the session identifier (`#255409204`) on the end?

Comment: I have, I still directs to the current Opp and Form.

Comment: Try with this format: `http://server/CRM/main.aspx?etc=3&extraqs=formid%3dC1EC704C-D29B-4786-806F-195D0A80CF07%7d&id=%7b<EnterOppIdHere>%7d&pagetype=entityrecord`

Comment: Awesome thanks, I had to use a combination of the original URL and the one suggested. The difference being the format of the formid; but it works now. Thank you very much; many hours spent banging my head.

Comment: I'll post that comment as an answer since it resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing the URL with this format:

```
http://server/CRM/main.aspx?etc=3&extraqs=formid%3dC1EC704C-D29B-4786-806F-195D‌​0A80CF07%7d&id=%7b<EnterOppIdHere>%7d&pagetype=entityrecord
```

Use the Entity Type Code (`etc` parameter) instead of the Name (`etn`) and note that everything after that should be part of the `extraqs` parameter.